Is it possible to reference a graph with velocity as Y axis and time as X axis so that I could pick values from it in ArcGIS Pro?
I want to be able to pick time-velocity measurement values from the graph. Can I somehow in ArcGIS Pro "geo"reference so that I could pick values from it? For example by creating a polyline that goes through measurement points and it gets values of measurements as XY coordinates.
Or what program would be suitable for this?


Your question makes no sense, if your graph axes are velocity and time how on earth is that meant to translate to real world XY coordinates?  What is possible in Arcpro is to plot a load of lines or points on a map and these are attributed with time and/or velocity. You can then chart that data and interact with it on the chart to select the original geometries on the map.

There are non-GIS ways of registering the graph and then extracting the x and y coordinates of the points, [see, for example, https://www.amsterchem.com/scanit.html] after which you can calculate the velocities (and accelerations) using formulae in something like Excel. However, this is impossible without any axis measurements -all you could do would be to assign dummy coordinates and obtain relative velocities.
